# We have $5$ red, $3$ blue and $2$ green balls. We take $3$ of them at random. What is the probability that they are of different colors?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> We have $5$ red, $3$ blue and $2$ green balls (balls of the same color are indistinguishable). We take $3$ of them at random. What is the probability that they are all of a different colors?

---

I have two ideas how to calculate and I think 2nd is right?

**First:** The number of all outcomes is $n = {10 \choose 3} = 120$ and the number of good outcomes is $m = 5\cdot 3\cdot 2 $ so  $$P= {m\over n} = 0,25$$

**Second:** Probability of choosing $1$ red/blue/green ball is ${5\over 10}$ /${3\over 10}$/${2\over 10}$. So choosing each color is ${3\over 100}$, but we have $6$ different arrangements of good choices that give us $$P = 6\cdot {3\over 100} = 0,18$$

Now which one is correct? Or it is no one? If you offer a new solution then **please write down a sample space and probability function** in your solution.

Comment: Before the problem can be solved, more information is needed: (1) are the balls selected with replacement or without replacement (i.e. after the first ball is selected, is it put back before the second ball is selected)? (2) what does "of a different color" mean, that the selected balls represent at least two different colors or that they represent all three colors?

Comment: Without replacement and no two are of the same color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first method is correct.

Let's correct your second method.  We are selecting balls *without* replacement.  Thus, the probability of selecting one red, one blue, and one blue in that order is 
$$\frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{9} \cdot \frac{2}{8} = \frac{1}{24}$$
As you said, there are $3!$ orders in which we could select the balls, which gives a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$, which agrees with the answer obtained using your first method.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first is correct and the second is flawed.

It looks like you don't consider fact that once you picked a red ball the chance to pick another red ball decreases.

For instance the chance to pick red then blue then green is in fact $\frac{5}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9}\cdot\frac{2}{8}$